# "guildMemberRoleAdd" Calling Back to Itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, basically I'm trying to write some code that if a user gets a specific role, it removes another one, and if the new role is removed, to add the original back. I'm going this for a few different pairs.

When I run the code like this, it works, but it also calls back into itself.

That's to say, because a new role is added or removed in "addHandler" & "removedHander", it goes back to the client.on in a recursive loop, getting bigger each time (since it cycles between both functions)

My question is simply this: is there any way to kill the function after it goes through it once so that it doesn't loop but that it'll still react if the roles are changed again?

```
client.on("guildMemberRoleAdd", function(member, role) {
        //console.log(member.user.tag+" acquired the role: "+role.name);
        addHandler.addHandler(member, role, client)
    });
    // Remove Role
    client.on("guildMemberRoleRemove", function(member, role) {
        //console.log(member.user.tag+" lost the role: "+role.name);
        removeHandler.removeHandler(member, role, client)
        //client.off('guildMemeberRoleRemove');
    })
```

I've tried looking into client.off, but every snippet of code I find online gives me the error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Any help will be appreciated!